# Синхронное выполнение кода на главном потоке

Tags: objective-c, многопоточность, ios7

Надо синхронно выполнить на главном потоке строчку кода

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Если синхронно из главного потока уйти на главный поток - будет `deadlock`.

проверка

```
if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

идеально подходит, но `dispatch_get_current_queue` запрещен, чем можно заменмть его в `iOS7`?

```
- (NSString *)getMyString {
   NSString *myString;
   __block UIWebView *webView;
   if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   } else {
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     });
  }
  myString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
  return myString; 
}
```

Comment: По-моему, вы можете просто использовать то что внутри блока else без всяких условий, по крайней мере мне такой финт пару раз встречался

Comment: @aknew будет deadlock, если вызвать синхронное выполнение `dispatch_sync` в том же потоке, из которого он вызывается. `dispatch_async` работает безотказно, но он не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может так:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *javascriptResult = self.getMyString;
});
```

и уберите все dispatch внутри геттера.

при этом можно не проверять какой там сейчас поток, но для проверки можно использовать `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: @iFreeman `[NSThread isMainThread]` работает, но логически это будет смешивание понятий очереди и потоков.
`dispatch_async` выполняется асинхронно, результат надо будет в `completion`-блоке возвращать, его можно использовать, если других вариантов нет

Comment: Согласен, предлагаю не проверять, а просто удостовериться, что вызов метода происходит на главное потоке, как я и указал в ответе.